# image as a background map in leaflet

Tags: leaflet

I have a georeferenced image and I need to use it as a basemap map, instead of OpenStreetMap. is there a way to do it with simple leaflet?

Answer (score 4):

If the image is not too big, you can avoid the tiling step by simply using an [`L.imageOverlay`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.0.3.html#imageoverlay):

> Used to load and display a single image over specific bounds of the map.

Usage example:

```js
var imageUrl = 'http://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg',
    imageBounds = [[40.712216, -74.22655], [40.773941, -74.12544]];

L.imageOverlay(imageUrl, imageBounds).addTo(map);
```

Demo: https://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/hijuh/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 3):

You can create tiles from the georefenced image with [gdal2tiles](http://www.gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html):

```
gdal2tiles georeference_image.tif output_folder
```

See the linked documentation for more options.

Now you can include the output directly to your leaflet map:

```
L.tileLayer('path/to/image/output_folder/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
{
attribution: 'Georeferenced Image', 
tms:true
}).addTo(map);
```